# shell scripting Multiple generator

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Hi :) Need help on a project, working on shell scripting and need to figure out how to print car names after certain numbers when they're divisible by certain numbers in a list.

Here's the generator, it takes two integers from the user, (Section where they're prompted not included), and prints the evens between those. I need to print car names after numbers divisible by: 5, 7, 10.

5 = Ford   7 = Bmw   10 = Rover

Generator:

```
for ((n = n1; n<= n2; ++n)); do 
    out=$(( $n % 2 )) 
    if [ $out -eg 0 ] ; then 
        echo "$n" 
    fi
done
```

Any help would be appreciated :( I'm completely clueless :(
Thanks

Comment: What are you asking for help with exactly? Does that code work? Do you understand how to find out which numbers need which car model (from the math perspective)? Do you understand how to do math in the shell?

Comment: I'm having some trouble forming the statement to do it, what I understand it needs to work like this: if for example I put 0 to 10, into the generator it prints the evens between 0 and 10, so, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. Then I need it to take these numbers and find identify those divisible by the numbers I stated and then it prints a car name after those, for example, 0, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, Rover. The way I figured it would work, in this example, 10 becomes 0 when worked out as a percentage. I'm a bit shaky on math in shell scripting honestly :(

Comment: Hint: Add some sane indentation to your code. It very often helps to see the flow of logic. Sometimes it will point you to an error. I'm sure you'll find it if you try :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
n1=0
n2=10

for ((n = n1; n <= n2; ++n)); do
    if (( n % 2 == 0)); then
        echo -n $n 
        if (( n %  5 == 0)); then
            echo -n ' Ford'
        fi
        if (( n %  7 == 0)); then
            echo -n ' BMW'
        fi
        if (( n % 10 == 0)); then
            echo -n ' Rover'
        fi
        echo
    fi
done
```

*Output*

```
0 Ford BMW Rover
2
4
6
8
10 Ford Rover
```

Not sure you want the `0` line containing names though, but that's how `%` works. You can add an explicit check for `0` if you wish.

Comment: Instead of `test $(( $n %  5)) == 0`, you can use `(( n % 5 == 0 ))`.

Comment: Erm is there any way I could write this as a series of if statements? For example split the cars into if statements as opposed to one function?

Comment: `$(seq $n1 $n2)` would be preferable to using back-quotes

Comment: I'm having a few issues, when I include the  solution, it generates the list of numbers and then states: seq Ford, Bmw, Rover and 10 and 50

Comment: @random1994 I am not sure I understand. Does it output something other than what I showed in my answer?

Comment: @totoro Think about all the wonderful nested `$(...)` my generation will produce ! </sarcasm>

Comment: @Aaron I do like Lisp!

Comment: @totoro heh, I was just kidding. I've only done a little Scheme myself, but I think that if in bash you need to nest subshells you should probably redesign your code

Comment: @Aaron Better now? No more sub shells.

Comment: Woops I wasn't talking about your code, but rather about the joke I made. This version's fine, but so was the previous one !

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v start=0 -v end=70 -v pat='5=Ford,7=Bmw,10=Rover'
      'BEGIN{n=split(pat,p,","); 
             for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
               {split(p[i],d,"=");
                a[d[1]]=d[2]}
             for(i=start;i<=end;i+=2)
               {printf "%s ",i; 
                for(k in a) 
                   if(i%k==0) 
                      printf "%s ", a[k]; 
                print ""}}'
```

instead of hard coding the fizzbuzz values, let the program handle it for you.  script parses the pattern and assigns divisor/value to a map `a`.  While iterating over from start to end two by two check for each divisor and if divides append the tag to the line.  Assumes start is entered as an even value if not need to guard for that too.

Comment: I think his brain will explode. Mine is about to :-)

Comment: I didn't notice that asking for bash script...  anyway `awk` is versatile for these kind of tasks.